# Hosting from home, can I change value of $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?

Tags: php, apache

I am thinking about hosting my website from home, I have set my host using noip like is: http://billzheng2004.no-ip.org/ -> http://68.99.177.59:8080/.

Now when I put the url in I get to the right place, but when I examine the webpage, all the links start with http://68.99.177.59:8080/ instead of http://billzheng2004.no-ip.org/.

When I check phpinfo(), I can see HTTP_HOST is the ip address too. Is there anyway it can make all links in php start with the url instead of the ip address?

Comment: http_host is basically what you typed into your browser to reach the web server. e.g. if you set up dns (or hosts file hack) to make `example.com` point to `127.0.0.1`, then `http://example.com` will make the http_host be
 `example.com`, while `http://127.0.0.1` would give you `127.0.0.1` as the http_host.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing when you inspect the page is what the XAMPP title page is generating.  However, once you replace this with your own content, common practice will be to write your links like

`<a href='/some/page.php>link</a>`

I'm not 100% sure how XAMPP creates those links, but

`<a href='http://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']?>/some/page.php>link</a>`

should produce an absolute path with the domain name that you typed to arrive at your page, whether that's an IP address, domain name, or localhost.